# How to use OpenNLP with Java?

Tags: java, nlp, pos-tagger, opennlp

I want to POStag an English sentence and do some processing. I would like to use openNLP. I have it installed

When I execute the command

```
I:\Workshop\Programming\nlp\opennlp-tools-1.5.0-bin\opennlp-tools-1.5.0>java -jar opennlp-tools-1.5.0.jar POSTagger models\en-pos-maxent.bin < Text.txt
```

It gives output POSTagging the input in Text.txt

```
    Loading POS Tagger model ... done (4.009s)
My_PRP$ name_NN is_VBZ Shabab_NNP i_FW am_VBP 22_CD years_NNS old._.


Average: 66.7 sent/s
Total: 1 sent
Runtime: 0.015s
```

I hope it installed properly?

Now how do i do this POStagging from inside a java application? I have added the openNLPtools, jwnl, maxent jar to the project but how do i invoke the POStagging?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here's some (old) sample code I threw together, with modernized code to follow:

```
package opennlp;

import opennlp.tools.cmdline.PerformanceMonitor;
import opennlp.tools.cmdline.postag.POSModelLoader;
import opennlp.tools.postag.POSModel;
import opennlp.tools.postag.POSSample;
import opennlp.tools.postag.POSTaggerME;
import opennlp.tools.tokenize.WhitespaceTokenizer;
import opennlp.tools.util.ObjectStream;
import opennlp.tools.util.PlainTextByLineStream;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class OpenNlpTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    POSModel model = new POSModelLoader().load(new File("en-pos-maxent.bin"));
    PerformanceMonitor perfMon = new PerformanceMonitor(System.err, "sent");
    POSTaggerME tagger = new POSTaggerME(model);

    String input = "Can anyone help me dig through OpenNLP's horrible documentation?";
    ObjectStream<String> lineStream =
            new PlainTextByLineStream(new StringReader(input));

    perfMon.start();
    String line;
    while ((line = lineStream.read()) != null) {

        String whitespaceTokenizerLine[] = WhitespaceTokenizer.INSTANCE.tokenize(line);
        String[] tags = tagger.tag(whitespaceTokenizerLine);

        POSSample sample = new POSSample(whitespaceTokenizerLine, tags);
        System.out.println(sample.toString());

        perfMon.incrementCounter();
    }
    perfMon.stopAndPrintFinalResult();
}
}
```

The output is:

```
Loading POS Tagger model ... done (2.045s)
Can_MD anyone_NN help_VB me_PRP dig_VB through_IN OpenNLP's_NNP horrible_JJ documentation?_NN

Average: 76.9 sent/s 
Total: 1 sent
Runtime: 0.013s
```

This is basically working from the POSTaggerTool class included as part of OpenNLP. The `sample.getTags()` is a `String` array that has the tag types themselves.

This requires direct file access to the training data, which is really, really lame.

An updated codebase for this is a little different (and probably more useful.)

First, a Maven POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.javachannel</groupId>
    <artifactId>opennlp-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.opennlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>opennlp-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>[6.8.21,)</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And here's the code, written as a test, therefore located in `./src/test/java/org/javachannel/opennlp/example`:

```
package org.javachannel.opennlp.example;

import opennlp.tools.cmdline.PerformanceMonitor;
import opennlp.tools.postag.POSModel;
import opennlp.tools.postag.POSSample;
import opennlp.tools.postag.POSTaggerME;
import opennlp.tools.tokenize.WhitespaceTokenizer;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class POSTest {
    private void download(String url, File destination) throws IOException {
        URL website = new URL(url);
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    @DataProvider
    Object[][] getCorpusData() {
        return new Object[][][]{{{
                "Can anyone help me dig through OpenNLP's horrible documentation?"
        }}};
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "getCorpusData")
    public void showPOS(Object[] input) throws IOException {
        File modelFile = new File("en-pos-maxent.bin");
        if (!modelFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Downloading model.");
            download("http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/en-pos-maxent.bin", modelFile);
        }
        POSModel model = new POSModel(modelFile);
        PerformanceMonitor perfMon = new PerformanceMonitor(System.err, "sent");
        POSTaggerME tagger = new POSTaggerME(model);

        perfMon.start();
        Stream.of(input).map(line -> {
            String whitespaceTokenizerLine[] = WhitespaceTokenizer.INSTANCE.tokenize(line.toString());
            String[] tags = tagger.tag(whitespaceTokenizerLine);

            POSSample sample = new POSSample(whitespaceTokenizerLine, tags);

            perfMon.incrementCounter();
            return sample.toString();
        }).forEach(System.out::println);
        perfMon.stopAndPrintFinalResult();
    }
}
```

This code doesn't actually *test* anything - it's a smoke test, if anything - but it should serve as a starting point. Another (potentially) nice thing is that it downloads a model for you if you don't have it downloaded already.

Comment: Thank you very very very very much.. I am finally on to the track?

Can you tell me where can i find the meaning of - NN MD, VB...and all these tags?

Comment: I have no idea! I'm working on that now, because I just realized - thanks to your question - how useful OpenNLP would be for a task of my own. :)

Comment: how to sort nouns and adjective from this output ?

Comment: You should migrate your example code, as models should not be loaded via `POSModelLoader` anymore (see Javadoc). Instead you can use the constructor `POSModel(InputStream in)` to load your model file via an `InputStream` referencing the actual model file.

Moreover, the class `POSModelLoader` was only present in previous releases of OpenNLP (versions <= 1.5.x). In the latest OpenNLP version 1.6.0 it was removed completely. Please update the example accordingly, as others tend to copy this outdated code and then (if it does not work...) ask new questions on StackOverflow ;)

Comment: In 1.6.0, the code as originally written actually ran properly, including with the constructor - it wasn't even marked as deprecated (although the PlainTextByLineStream was deprecated.) Are you using the 1.6.0 snapshot? 

In any event, I updated the code to be more 1.6 compliant. Thanks!

Comment: Is their updated code for the top code, as in similar style(I did see the bottom code but it differs quite a bit from the top).

Answer (score 10):

The URL http://bulba.sdsu.edu/jeanette/thesis/PennTags.html does not work anymore. I found the below on the 14th slide at http://www.slideshare.net/gagan1667/opennlp-demo

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The above answer does provide a way to use the existing models from OpenNLP but if you need to train your own model, maybe the below can help:

Here is a detailed tutorial with full code:

https://dataturks.com/blog/opennlp-pos-tagger-training-java-example.php

Depending upon your domain, you can build a dataset either automatically or manually. Building such a dataset manually can be really painful, tools like [POS tagger](https://dataturks.com/projects/Dataturks/Demo%20POS%20Tagging%20Project) can help make the process much easier.

**Training data format**

Training data is passed as a text file where each line is one data item. Each word in the line should be labeled in a format like "word_LABEL", the word and the label name is separated by an underscore '_'.

```
anki_Brand overdrive_Brand
just_ModelName dance_ModelName 2018_ModelName
aoc_Brand 27"_ScreenSize monitor_Category
horizon_ModelName zero_ModelName dawn_ModelName
cm_Unknown 700_Unknown modem_Category
computer_Category
```

**Train model**

The important class here is POSModel, which holds the actual model. We use class POSTaggerME to do the model building. Below is the code to build a model from training data file

```
public POSModel train(String filepath) {
  POSModel model = null;
  TrainingParameters parameters = TrainingParameters.defaultParams();
  parameters.put(TrainingParameters.ITERATIONS_PARAM, "100");

  try {
    try (InputStream dataIn = new FileInputStream(filepath)) {
        ObjectStream<String> lineStream = new PlainTextByLineStream(new InputStreamFactory() {
            @Override
            public InputStream createInputStream() throws IOException {
                return dataIn;
            }
        }, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        ObjectStream<POSSample> sampleStream = new WordTagSampleStream(lineStream);

        model = POSTaggerME.train("en", sampleStream, parameters, new POSTaggerFactory());
        return model;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;

}
```

**Use model to do tagging.**

Finally, we can see how the model can be used to tag unseen queries:

```
    public void doTagging(POSModel model, String input) {
    input = input.trim();
    POSTaggerME tagger = new POSTaggerME(model);
    Sequence[] sequences = tagger.topKSequences(input.split(" "));
    for (Sequence s : sequences) {
        List<String> tags = s.getOutcomes();
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(input.split(" ")) +" =>" + tags);
    }
}
```