# OpenNlp doesn't run in my computer

Tags: opennlp

I start to work with OpenNlp . First i download apache-opennlp-1.5.3-bin.tar.gz from http://opennlp.apache.org/cgi-bin/download.cgi, unzip it and found some jar file in it's lib folder.

In eclipse i open a new project and create a class OpenNlpTest.java and past code from the answer of this question[open NLP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836148/how-to-use-opennlp-with-java).Then i add those jar files in this project.

When i run this project it shows this:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   opennlp.tools.cmdline.TerminateToolException: The POS Tagger model
>   file does not exist! Path: D:\workspaces\OpenNLPTest\en-pos-maxent.bin
>     at
>   opennlp.tools.cmdline.CmdLineUtil.checkInputFile(CmdLineUtil.java:81)
>     at opennlp.tools.cmdline.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:53)  at
>   OpenNlpTest.main(OpenNlpTest.java:16)

then i download model from http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/ and put this .zip file in D:\workspaces\OpenNLPTest.

**But still it shows the same Exception**

Comment: Is the file in your `OpenNLPTest` directory definitely called `en-pos-maxent.bin` and not `en-pos-maxent.bin.zip`?  Remember the `.bin` files are zip compressed but they shouldn't have a `.zip` extension.

Comment: @IanRoberts I download models from [model](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/). It shows `.bin` file but download as a `.zip` file.

Comment: The name of the file needs to match the name you have told OpenNLP to look for - you either need to rename the model file to the name OpenNLP expects or change the name you pass to the POS tagger to match the name of the file on disk.

Comment: Thaks **IanRoberts** very very much. I just put `model = new POSModelLoader().load(new File("en-pos-maxent.zip"))'; instead of `model = new POSModelLoader().load(new File("en-pos-maxent.bin"))';

Answer (score 0):

Promoting comment to answer since OP not around for a while ...

Thanks IanRoberts very very much. I just put

```
model = new
POSModelLoader().load(new File("en-pos-maxent.zip"));
```

instead of

```
model = new POSModelLoader().load(new File("en-pos-maxent.bin"));
```