# How to correctly integrate OpenNLP API in an Eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, api, opennlp

I want to use the sentencer through the API in my Java program, which is very well documented here:
http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.sentdetect.detection.api,
and has also been described here:
[How to use OpenNLP with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836148/how-to-use-opennlp-with-java)

I downloaded the `apache-opennlp-1.6.0-bin.tar.gz` from here: http://apache.lauf-forum.at/opennlp/opennlp-1.6.0/

But what I can't find anywhere is how to install OpenNLP such that I can import it in my Java programm. I tried to simply put the `.jar` in my workspace, which didn't help. I don't find any documentation on that on the OpenNLP page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured it out myself.

I simply had to put the openNLP folder somewhere, then right-click the Project and go to

```
Build Path --> Configure Build Path
```

click the `Libraries` tab, click `Add External JARs...` and navigate to the OpenNLP `jar` file.

Then I could import classes, such as

`import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetectorME;`

without any problems.

Comment: If this is not the intended way or if there are other, better ways of doing this, please share that information anyhow!